# View remaining stamina

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So we know that as when you sprint the stamina 'amount' decreases, what I'd like to know is if there's a way to see the amount of stamina they have left before they hit their 'limit' and it starts deducting health? Is there anything the character does to give a clue it might be getting low?

Comment: Well they start breathing heavily but other than that I don't know. I think they should have replaced the air bar with a stamina one and made an air bar pop up when underwater

Comment: There's an air bar? Where's that? My understanding is it's: Green - Health, Blue - Armour, Yellow - Special.

Comment: Oh. Never mind then. Armor would make sense. I thought the blue bar would go down underwater. So there is neither a stamina nor an air bar. That's pretty lame

Comment: There is a stamina bar, but only when you're doing the Triathlon.

Comment: @Nolonar Oh right, I haven't done one of those yet. I thought of this when I had to race a girl near the beach and I had no idea how what my stamina level was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no stamina bar, the only exception is when you do the Triathlon race.
One way to find out when you are running low on stamina before starting losing health during "normal" activities it's by looking at the health bar, it starts flashing before starting draining your health.

Comment: Thanks, that was driving me absolutely mad. Being colour blind does NOT help with this at all. Ramming the 2/3 bars together is very confusing for me.